# MPAndroidChart LineChart labels on axis disappear when fragment is resumed

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, mpandroidchart

I have a problem updating the data in a chart. When I change the settings and come back to this fragment or when I go out of the app and come back, the chart apparently changes its size and hide the labels in its axis. However, if I navigate through the app and come back, the chart is displaying well.

**Screenshot of correct display**

[image]

**Screenshot of axis labels disappearing**

[image]

My context is the following:
I have a fragment where I observe the viewmodel in onViewCreated. When the data is successfully retrieved, I update the chart. I have tried also to make a flag to make sure that the call to set up the chart is only called once, but that doesn't work either. So the problem is not related to how many times this call is made.

```
viewModel.forecast.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { resource ->
            if (resource != null && resource.status.isSuccessful()){
                   ChartUtilities.setUpChart(
                        viewModel.forecastOfNextHours().subList(0, 9),
                        binding.lineChart,
                        "Temperature of the next 24 hours",
                        isMetric
                    )
}
```

In ChartUtilities.kt:

```
object ChartUtilities {

    fun setUpChart(list: List<ForecastListItem>, lineChart: LineChart, label: String, isMetric: Boolean){
        //lineChart.clear()
        val (values, yValues, xAxisValues) = fillData(list, isMetric)
        val data = configureDataSet(values, label)
        customSettings(lineChart, data, xAxisValues, yValues)
        //lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    private fun configureDataSet(
        values: ArrayList<Entry>,
        label: String
    ): LineData {
        val set1 = LineDataSet(values, label)
        set1.axisDependency = YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT
        set1.color = ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue()
        set1.valueTextColor = ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue()
        set1.lineWidth = 4.0f
        set1.setDrawCircles(false)
        set1.setDrawValues(false)
        set1.fillAlpha = 65
        set1.fillColor = Color.RED
        set1.highLightColor = Color.rgb(244, 117, 117)
        set1.setDrawCircleHole(false)
        set1.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER

        // create a data object with the data sets
        val data = LineData(set1)
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        data.setValueTextSize(9f)
        return data
    }

    private fun fillData(list: List<ForecastListItem>, isMetric: Boolean): Triple<ArrayList<Entry>, ArrayList<Double>, ArrayList<String>> {
        val values = ArrayList<Entry>()
        val yValues = ArrayList<Double>()
        val xAxisValues = arrayListOf<String>()
        list.forEachIndexed { index, forecastItem ->
            xAxisValues.add(forecastItem.getHourOfDay())
            var temperature = forecastItem.getTemperature()!!
            if (!isMetric)
                temperature = WeatherUtils.celsiusToFahrenheit(temperature)
            yValues.add(temperature)
            values.add(Entry(index.toFloat(), temperature.toFloat()))
        }
        return Triple(values, yValues, xAxisValues)
    }

    private fun customSettings(chart: LineChart, data: LineData, xAxisValues: ArrayList<String>, yAxisValues: ArrayList<Double>){
        chart.data = data
        customChart(chart)
        customLegend(chart)
        customXAxis(chart, xAxisValues)
        customYAxis(chart, yAxisValues)
        val rightAxis = chart.axisRight
        rightAxis.isEnabled = false
    }

    private fun customChart(chart: LineChart) {
        chart.description.isEnabled = false
        chart.setTouchEnabled(false)

        //chart.dragDecelerationFrictionCoef = 0.9f
        // enable scaling and dragging
        chart.isDragEnabled = false
        chart.setScaleEnabled(false)
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
        chart.isHighlightPerDragEnabled = true
        // set an alternative background color
        chart.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
        chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
    }

    private fun customLegend(chart: LineChart) {
        val l = chart.legend
        l.isEnabled = true
        l.verticalAlignment = Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP
        l.textColor = Color.WHITE
    }

    private fun customXAxis(
        chart: LineChart,
        xAxisValues: ArrayList<String>
    ) {
        val xAxis = chart.xAxis
        xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
        xAxis.textSize = 12f
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true)
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
        xAxis.textColor = Color.WHITE
        //xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
        xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(false)
        xAxis.granularity = 2f // three hours
        xAxis.axisMaximum = xAxisValues.size.toFloat()
        xAxis.labelCount = xAxisValues.size
        xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisValues)
        xAxis.isEnabled = true

    }

    private fun customYAxis(
        chart: LineChart,
        yAxisValues: ArrayList<Double>
    ) {
        val leftAxis = chart.axisLeft
        leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART)
        leftAxis.textColor = Color.WHITE
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true)
        leftAxis.isGranularityEnabled = true
        leftAxis.axisMinimum = yAxisValues.min()?.minus(10)?.toFloat()!!
        leftAxis.axisMaximum = yAxisValues.max()?.plus(10)?.toFloat()!!
        leftAxis.yOffset = -9f
        leftAxis.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a very late answer, but I had exactly the same issue and stumbled upon your question. I'd intermittently see the axes disappear when scrolling between different charts (I had them in a RecyclerView).

I solved it by deleting the following line, which I see you also have in your code:

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The javadoc for that method says that we should avoid manually setting it unless we know what we're doing (which I don't!).

I also found that increasing the values to the following worked for me:

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(60, 0, 50, 60);
```